# Difference between (function designator) and {function pointer}?

Tags: c, struct, grouping, function-pointers

In clang, a pointer to a function and the designation/designator have distinct resulting grouping symbols, **parenthesis** compared to ***curly braces*** as seen in the code fragments further down.

What is:

`type * type(*)(type)`

used for and versus/what is:

`type *(type)`

used for? Curly braces are for use in lists, compound statements and aggregates while parenthesis are primarily used for ordering, grouping, casting and arguments.

It looks like the first is a type reference to a function  pointer accepting a specific type argument which, if enclosed in parenthesis either orders the group be evaluated individually if part of a larger expression or creates a cast which after the resolution of the function would convert it to a specific value of the return type of the specified size and alignment requirements instead of the binary sequence containing the value.

The second one is in a block with curly braces and thus a compound object or statement block since I can't see how it would be attached to an aggregate though it may be reference to a function body result of a call.

The second snippet looks like a type reference to a type defined or object group and, since a type may not share a name with an object, effectively making it a keyword, I presume that this somehow creates a named object that is multiplied with itself, or is a reverse cast or something since keywords with an asterisk have no real use aside from object declarations.

`P`

Why does the initial have ***parenthesis*** enclosing the symbol whereas the second symbol uses ***curly braces***?

For example, the following code fragment when compiled,

.

`(*function)(1);`

mentions the symbol in the comments after compiling is noted as:

`(type *(*)(type))`

with ***parenthesis*** encompassing the representation in the compilation log of the console.

.

whereas:

.

`function(1);`

mentions the symbol in the comments after compiling is noted as:

`{type *(type)}`

with ***curly braces*** encompassing the representation in the compilation log of the console.

.

**What is the distinction between the two for, and under what circumstances is it practically applied in any usual/useful contexts?**

My general observations of the syntax and semantics of the C language suggest to me the first appears to be a basic ordered-group expression which may be used in a comma-separated list or as a function parameter whereas the second appears to be a struct, union or block statement.

I was exploring function pointers and so I tried both and those two notes were clang's comments of the compilation. None of the other 5 posts I read seemed to clarify the nature of the grouping symbols in any context but did provided additional insight to function pointers and their applications.

Thank you!

Comment: What is “resolves to…”? That is a sentence fragment without context. Is it a quote from somewhere? Where? It’s a Clang message? Show the full message, with context, including a [mre].

Comment: I updated the message to reflect the code parts in the console and source as well as emphasized the components in bold which were the confusing parts. Simply, under what circumstances would that delineation of the grouping symbol be of use or distinction regarding a pointer having a parenthetical surrounding versus a structural surrounding be of value in my coding practice?

Comment: If the text `Note: (*type *(*)(type))` and `Note: {type *(type)}` is output from the compiler, then edit the question to show the exact input to the compiler that reproduces it, including the source code, the command line, and the compiler version. If it is text that appears on the Internet somewhere, give a URL for it. If it is text from some other source, then give a bibliographic citation for it. As it stands, describing it as “the comments after compiling” is unclear.

Comment: More simply, what is: type * type(*)(type) used and what is type *(type) used for?

Comment: Edit the question to show actual examples in context. Show exact input to the compiler that produces the output being asked about.

Answer (score -1):

function designator is an expression with function type.

for example in

```
a = foo(x);
```

foo is a function designator.

`Function pointer` is a reference to the function. Function designators decay to function pointers when used as values.

```
int (*fptr)(int) = foo;
```

Comment: Why is the distinction made then between a designator of function and pointer to a function? Is there some operational application that requires it for the developer in some rare context? Is it an implementation distinction specifically for the compiler?